# How to fill the dataset with C# from oracle database

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, .net-2.0

I am trying to fill the oracle dataset == NULL;

I am using it with a .NET Framework 2.0 with C#

Comment: are you receiving an error?  post your sample code so we can see what you have tried to do, are you using odp or the deprecated system.data.oracleclient?

Answer (score 14):

here is a system.data.oracleclient example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx (this example is 1.1 but will work the same with 2.0)

(snippet from link)

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=Oracle8i;Integrated Security=yes");
Conn.Open;
OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "sp_pkg.getdata";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("a1", OracleType.Cursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("a2", OracleType.Cursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

here is an ODP (recommended) example:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/windows/odpnet/DSPopulate/ViewProducts.cs.html

(snippet from link)

```
//Instantiate OracleDataAdapter to create DataSet
productsAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();

//Fetch Product Details
productsAdapter.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT " +
                                                  "Product_ID , " +
                                                  "Product_Name , " +
                                                  "Product_Desc , " +
                                                  "Category, " +
                                                  "Price " +
                                                  "FROM Products",conn);

//Instantiate DataSet object
productsDataSet = new DataSet("productsDataSet");

//Fill the DataSet with data from 'Products' database table
productsAdapter.Fill(productsDataSet, "Products");

//setting 'productsDataSet' as  the datasouce and 'Products' table
//as the table to which the 'productsDataGrid' is Bound.
productsDataGrid.SetDataBinding(productsDataSet,"Products");
```

Comment: Hello from the distant future. The last step is not part of this particular question. But if you intend to do any CRUD operation on the data set that's the way to go.