# How to return Dataset result from function in Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle11g

How can we return dataset result from function in oracle without using curson and type.

My problem is that when my function returns the result, the result is in comma(,) delimited. I want result in tabular format...

My Sample Query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION res_set_2(obj_id VARCHAR2)
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
   my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   OPEN my_cursor FOR 
   SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t2.bankingId=obj_id;
  RETURN my_cursor;
END;
```

Suggest me best solution..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you intend to use this function ? what's wrong with `refcursor` ? what's the problem with a `type` ? why can't you just run the query (why do you need to wrap it in plsql) ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade Problem is that the result is comma separated, and we want the result in dataset/tabular format.

Comment: 1- when you say `dataset` do you mean `C# DataSet`? 2- when you say `tabular format`, will xml do ?

Comment: Yes Dataset means c# DataSet... yes it is fine if i m getting result in xml format.. If u have solution of both Dataset and xml please let me know.. i m OK with both the solution..

Comment: How do you process the result of this function?

Comment: I just want to call the oracle function which should return the result in such a way that, using c# i can convert it to dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the results of a query in XML with [amlagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION res_set_2(obj_id VARCHAR2)
   RETURN varchar2 AS
   my_xml varchar2(32767);
BEGIN

   SELECT xmlelement("DATASET", xmlagg(
                       xmlelement("ROW", xmlforest(t1.col1, t1.col2, ..., t2.col1, ...))
                                      )).getStringVal()
     INTO my_xml 
     FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
    WHERE t2.bankingId=obj_id;

   RETURN my_xml;
END;
```

Note that I returned varchar2 for simplicity, I have never tried to get XMLTYPE in C#

As for a DataSet, maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668364/how-to-fill-the-dataset-with-c-sharp-from-oracle-database) can help

Comment: @amlagg Thanks for solution it's working fine, but one issue, my_xml object has size limit of (32767). i have result in lacs which gives an error of size limit, so what should i use instead of my_xml varchar2(32767).

Comment: Either try to use XMLTYPE (and then remove the `.getStringVal()`) or use a clob ( and then replace  `.getStringVal()` with  `.getClobVal()`) . I think that the XMLTYPE is the better way