# Reading data for oracle reader to fill datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have form that has `textbox` for product ID when user enter an product id 
I am getting details of product (like PRODUCT_DESC,UNIT_PRICE,...etc) from oracle database and then fill it in `datagridview` to create list of purchased product

I tried to load dataset but thats will remove the old record when adding new product ID

I tried to loop on `dataset` and extract values I want and then add them to their column in `datagridview` the loop here is useless since there is only one record but that wont load data on the `datagridview`

please how to do it ??

and is there any better way to do that ?

```
    private void SelectedProductData()
    {
        string connstr = @"Data Source=orcl; User Id=user; password=pwd;";
        string cmdtxt = @"SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
                                 PRODUCT_DESC,
                                 UNIT_PRICE,
                                 QUANTITY,
                                 MEASUREMENT_UNIT,
                                 MANUFACTORY
                          FROM WAREHOUSE
                            WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :P_Product_ID";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = cmdtxt;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_Product_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = TB_Product_ID.Text;

            conn.Open();
            OracleDataReader oraReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(oraReader);

            while (oraReader.Read())
            {
                DGV_INVOICE.CurrentCell.Value = oraReader.GetString(0);
            }
            //foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            //{
            //    DGV_INVOICE.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[0]["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString();
            //}
        }
    }
```

**Code Update**

```
private void TB_Product_ID_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectedProductData();
}
```

method

```
private void SelectedProductData()
{
    string connstr = @"Data Source=JDT; User Id=admin; password=admin;";
    string cmdtxt = @"SELECT PRODUCT_ID,
                             PRODUCT_DESC,
                             UNIT_PRICE,
                             QUANTITY,
                             MEASUREMENT_UNIT,
                             MANUFACTORY
                      FROM WAREHOUSE
                        WHERE PRODUCT_ID = :P_Product_ID";

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = cmdtxt;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_Product_ID", OracleDbType.Int32)).Value = TB_Product_ID.Text;

        OracleDataReader oraReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Load(oraReader);

        while (oraReader.Read())
        {
            DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = oraReader.GetValue(2);
            //dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = oraReader.GetString(2);
            //dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = oraReader.GetString(3);
            //dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = oraReader.GetString(4);

            DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Add(dgvRow);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: @JohnG I have not set the data source to DataGridView First 
1. because I have made column manually and I want to fill rows from database and insert each column value at column I want ... because between these columns there are calculation columns that will be calculated according to data I get from database like the total price will be calculated according to unit_price value from database multiplied by number of unit.... and so on ....
second 
2. if I load the DataGridView that will remove the previous entered record and load the new one ... sorry for my bad English .Hope it is clear now

Comment: @JohnG I have upload an image to make things more clear I m not re-reading data twice from database I am reading data I want to insert it into a specific column in `DataGridView` that will lunch an event on `DataGridView` which will calculate column Total Price if I load the dataset as I search and found on the net that will remove previous record and load the new record ... example I have entered product 1 with price 1000  and named test1 when user request new product that will not laod another record in `DataGridView`that will load new record into `DataGridView`and remove old one

Comment: @JohnG Yes Image shows what user sees and image updated to let you know total price column and column 1.2.3 comes from database according to product ID user will enter number 123 are where each one should be load it it should don't be load as extra column at end of DataGridView columns I have made when I load the dataset like 1 in column 1 and  2 in column 2 at your right hand not as shown now ... read marks is that column 1 multiplied with column 2 minus column 3 will result in data in column total price which is the calculation column I talked about

Comment: @JohnG column 1 at left hand should be in column 1 at right hand that what numbers means

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fill the dataset with C# from oracle database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668364/how-to-fill-the-dataset-with-c-sharp-from-oracle-database)

Comment: @Sam If understand it correctly, you want to add new row in the datagridview with product details whenever you get productdetails from database for the provided productId. Please correct me if I am not getting it right?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel thanks but that wont show me how to insert value into specific column within datagridview plus the oracle link inside that post   not working ... I am using dot net 4 maybe there is more efficient way am I right ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya YES exactly but in spsfice column in DataGridView NOT just load returned record from database as they are you can say controlling the way of inserting data from database into datagridview

Comment: Is it web application or windows application?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya windows form application using dot net 4 and oracle database 11G R2 visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have correct implementation of how to add new row to the datagridview.

Once you have the data available in reader you can use following logic to add new row and set the column values for the datagridview.

```
while (oraReader.Read())
{
    DataGridViewRow dgvRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell());
    dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = true;
    dgvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());
    dgvRow.Cells[1].Value = oraReader.GetString(1);

    //AND so on....
    //You need to add appropriate cells to the row and assign values to the cells. 

    //And finally add the row to the data grid view.
    DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Add(dgvRow);
}
```

Here, the while loop will be executed only once because reader will have data for only one proudct. But this will create a new row in the datagridview and set the values of the columns.

Comment: Thank alot for your help and that looks like what I want but I am getting error Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. I check the Edit Mode for DataGridView and its EditProgrammatically and all columns NOT read Only Columns ... anything else to check ?

Comment: At which line do you get this error? Are you calling "SelectedProductData" method on button click?

Comment: yes I am calling `SelectedProductData` on button click and I am getting error at `while (oraReader.Read())`

Comment: Can you share new version of method "SelectedProductData" ?

Comment: Try removing " DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(oraReader);" from the method. You are not using the reader anywhere in the method.

Comment: YES I shared the new code and sorry I was calling method on botton click but now I am calling method on leave event ...

Comment: I did remove the datatable and dt.load and error now is Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index on line `dgvRow.Cells[0].Value = oraReader.GetValue(1);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133662/discussion-between-chetan-ranpariya-and-sam).

Comment: Okay I am over there too